# How much MPa of pressure can human cells survive?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane

Is there any research on this topic with concrete numbers? I found some papers of high pressure tests on microbes, but not on human/mammal cells. What I want to find is true "crush depth" for a human (assuming full liquid breathing and CO2 scrubbing from veins).

One in one Youtube video author claimed that 1000 m (10 MPa/100 Bar) is maximum depth human can reach, because at such pressure human cells will fail. Membranes will get so stiff, that it will fail to exchange oxygen/nutrients/energy, so, effectively, neurons will die at such depth. Author didn't provide any sources whatsoever for such claims, though. He just provided Blobfish (Psychrolutes marcidus) example. It has jelly-like, very soft cell membranes that at 1.6 km depth are as rigid as our own membranes at sea level, but when brought to sea level pressure loose structural integrity.

Yet, I highly doubt this claim, considering that Sperm Whales casually dive to 2 km depth and Cuvier's beaked whale dives 3 km. They do not turn into jelly like Blobfish at the surface, yet still manage to remain at such huge pressure as 30 MPa for hours. Of-course, they don't live permanently at such depths, but human diver is not required to live there too - just survive and go back without major trauma.

So if a Sperm whale can do it, can't we too? Or can we? At what pressure our cells will fail?

Comment: How do you propose the research be conducted? On paid volunteers? Prisoners? Illegal immigrants? What difference does knowing this make, practically (or scientifically)? If people need to go deeper, they get into mini subs that can withstand great pressures now. Nobody dies finding the answer. (This kind of *extreems of endurance* research was done, oh, 70-80 years ago...)

Comment: Well, with modern technology there is no need to even go into the ocean. And this is very cheap experiment for somebody with required tech. Just get some human liver or neuron cells, put them into pressure chamber and start increasing pressure while monitoring their status. As simple as that. It is really weird that nobody don this yet, as it is very important to know our theoretical limits so that we can improve our exoskeletons (yes I call body exoskeleton, because the human is neuron connections and currents within them, and body is just an external structure that supports this system).

Comment: Seems like nobody in the World can provide any information on this topic. I will assume, for now, hard limit of 3 km depth, judging from deep diving whales. I don't know why they don't dive deeper, maybe there is no food there, but maybe they actually reached hard limit of what surface mammal can achieve in terms of cell membrane pressure.

Comment: @anongoodnurse at the very least, tests on mice might give pretty accurate results for surface optimised organism's crush depth.

Comment: Why kill a mouse for such useless information?